# How do you make subversion act on files not in a changelist?

Tags: svn

Subversion's changelist feature allows you to put a label on certain files. For example, I have a changelist called 'do not commit'. How do I commit everything but the files in this or any other changelists, i.e. modified files that do not belong to a changelist?

Answer (score 1):

I know that both [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.net/) use what's called an ignore-on-commit changelist. This doesn't affect the command line client, and both are Windows (and Visual Studio) tools. I don't know of a program with such a change list on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of roundabout way of doing it, but you could write a script that tags all files not already on your "do not commit" changelist into another changelist. Then, commit all the changes on that new changelist.